# C# ExecuteReader() error. Need to ouput SQL query to textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to have to basically have one **textbox** that asks for an ID then have a **button** that when pressed sends the ID to a query something like this:

```
 str = "SELECT TOP 1 [Sender Name],[Subject]  from [OLE DB Destination] WHERE [CHAT #] ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

then output the results of that query into either a textbox or several in case I increase the amount of rows I want to output.

Right now I have this but it is not working:

```
namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USBA01\\OU3;Initial Catalog=HOU_Project;Integrated Security=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT TOP 1 [Sender Name],[Subject] "
                            + " from[OLE DB Destination] WHERE[CHAT #] = :chatId ";
            con.Open();
            using (con)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("chatId", textBox1.Text); 

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    textBox2.Text = reader[0] + " " + reader[1]; 
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an "incorrect syntax" error with this line:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I am new to C# so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your sql query is invalid. Run the query against the server first. You might try: SELECT TOP 1 [your col] from [your database] WHERE [your col] = @param

Comment: Remove that colon in front of chatID.  You can replace the HasRows and Read() lines with just a `if (reader.Read())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `OleDb` you need to use the `OleD objects like` OleDbConnection`,` OleDbCommand`, etc.
2. Your query syntax is wrong as you are missing spaces. You need spaces between `FROM` and the table name, and between `WHERE` and the column name.

   I'm not sure what `:chatId` is, but if you are looking to connect against Oracle then use the Oracle database client or the `OleDb` objects as mentioned above.
3. Also, your use of `SqlConnection` is problematic; you need to create an instance only when needed and dispose the whole instance when done.